# How can I create an AWS AppRunner role that allows my application to query from DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, amazon-app-runner

I have a small app that reads from DynamoDB and is deployed with AppRunner. I'm having trouble giving AppRunner access to Dynamo. I created an IAM role with the policies I think I need but it does not show up when I open the security configuration for this AppRunner service.

Answer (score 15):

I would guess that your role is lacking a trust relationship for App Runner, e.g. meaning the right configuration that allows an App Runner Instance to assume this role.

To fix that, you would go to your role, then trust relation ship, then edit.
Here is an example, how that trust relationship should look like to be selectable as instance role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "tasks.apprunner.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can also take a look at the [AWS App Runner Workshop](https://www.apprunnerworkshop.com/).

They use [this CloudFormation template](https://github.com/andskli/repostatus-gh-demo/blob/main/hack/apprunner-prereqs-cfn.yaml) to create an App Runner instance role.

Comment: This is the answer. The OP is referring to the Security section of the App Runner configuration wizard. The AWS Documentation refers to the "apprunner.amazonaws.com" service principal name but the "tasks.apprunner.amazonaws.com" service principal name is what is actually needed in order for the IAM Role to show up in the drop down list when configuring app runner security via the web console.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This worked for me when there was no service role appearing in the dropdown section of the Apprunner's console. To add a bit more detail to this answer, there is also no Apprunner option in the "AWS Service" option when creating a new role. The "Custom Trust Policy" option was how I created a version that appeared in the Apprunner dropdown menu.

Comment: My problem was that I had "build.apprunner.amazonaws.com" instead of "tasks.apprunner.amazonaws.com" for the instance role. "build.apprunner.amazonaws.com" is used for the ECR role

Answer (score 3):

I was there too. Here is the cli version of Julian Spung's answer. (Ref: https://zenn.dev/becominn/articles/3c06bc732f8775)

**Create role file**

```
cat << EOF > apprunner-role-policy.json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "tasks.apprunner.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

**Create Role**

```
aws iam create-role \
 --role-name apprunner-role \
 --assume-role-policy-document file://apprunner-role-policy.json
```

**Attach your service permissions**

```
aws iam attach-role-policy \
 --role-name apprunner-role \
 --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more concrete code example with the cdk:

```
  const dockerImageAsset = new DockerImageAsset(
    scope,
    `AppDockerImage`,
    {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "../"),
      platform: Platform.LINUX_AMD64,
    }
  );
  const instanceRole = new iam.Role(scope, 'AppRunnerInstanceRole', {
    assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('tasks.apprunner.amazonaws.com')
  })

  const accessRole = new iam.Role(scope, 'AppRunnerBuildRole', {
    assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('build.apprunner.amazonaws.com')
  })
  const myTable = dynamodb.Table.fromTableName(
    scope,
    `MyDb`,
    `MyDb`
  );
  const policy = new iam.PolicyStatement({
    effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
    actions: [
      "dynamodb:GetItem",
      "dynamodb:Query",
      "dynamodb:Scan",
      "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
    ],
    resources: [myTable.tableArn],
  });
  instanceRole.addToPolicy(policy);

  new Service(scope, "service", {
    serviceName: `App${suffix.toLowerCase()}`,
    instanceRole,
    accessRole,
    source: Source.fromAsset({
      imageConfiguration: {
        port: 3000,
        environmentVariables: {
          CONTAINER: "true",
          NODE_ENV: "production",
        },
      },
      asset: dockerImageAsset,
    }),
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! This should have been in the CDK docs :)

Comment: very important to distinguish between instanceRole and accessRole, thanks for highlighting that

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you read and understand the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/security_iam_service-with-iam.html). To access DynamoDb you need to create an appropriate policy and attach it to your service's instance role.

> The instance role is an optional role that App Runner uses to provide
> permissions to AWS service actions that your application code calls.
> Before creating an App Runner service, use IAM to create a service
> role with the permissions that your application code needs. You can
> then pass this role to App Runner in the CreateService API, or when
> using the App Runner console to create a service.

The CreateService API is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/api/API_CreateService.html). You need to find the ARN of the role and provide it to the InstanceRoleArn parameter.

Comment: I did exaclty that. The problem is that roles don't show up in the CreateService API :( Is there a reason why they are not showing up?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't show up? It is the InstanceRoleArn parameter.

Comment: I promise. I have refreshed, created a new AppRunner service, tried everything... the role is not there

Comment: @dave refer to Julian Spung's answer. It solves the problem.